# Why does pasting a certain character change the chronology of the characters in the whole row?

Tags: keyboard, ascii, copy-paste

I've got this funny problem when trying to copy and paste the character٭  It doesn't let me get my cursor behind it and swapps the whole line of characters (see gif). Also the cursor has a funny double cursor, when I highlight ٭

I think I activated some strange mode here accidently with some keys. Anyone know whats going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This character٭ (Arabic 5-pointed star) is naturally designed for a right-to-left writing language, such as Arabic. The computer recognizes it and automatically switches the cursor to writing right-to-left.